# Android IDE / Eclipse frequently looses or resets perspective

Tags: android, eclipse, ide

For some reason Android's IDE / Eclipse frequently forgets my customized perspective (mainly: hide right panel, show menu LogCat, Devices, Emulator Control).

There are no crashes or lockups when this happens. I quit Eclipse properly, and the next time I start it up, it's like it was reset sometimes. No error message to indicate what happened.

I've tried saving a new perspective, but that gets deleted too.

Any tips what I should be checking?

Android Developer Tools
Build: v22.3.0-887826
Windows 7 x64